# file path in Java

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I want to read a text file in which contains abbreviations to manipulate a string.

Here is how I am reading in the file:

```
public Shortener( String inAbbreviationsFilePath ) throws FileNotFoundException {

    Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(inAbbreviationsFilePath));
```

I have written another java application which is used to manipulate the string called utility.

```
public class ShortenerUtility {
    public static void main(String[]args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Shortener sh = new Shortener()
```

so I am trying to execute the following in cmd:

```
java ShortenerUtilty(filepath) "String to manipulate"
```

I get an error saying 
couldn't find or load main class ShortenerUtility followed by the path that I try to enter

Comment: This doesn't compile, so can't be executed.. Also you might want to read some beginner tutorial

Comment: That's not how "java" works. You either need to read more about how to compile and run your code using java/javac, or get an IDE like Eclipse...

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to pass command line arguments to a program, you should always pass them **after** the name of the class plus at least one space, not with `()`.

The line you have used causes java to look for a class called `java ShortenerUtilty(filepath)`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to provide argument to main method & the way you are providing arguments is wrong

```
 java ShortenerUtilty(filepath) "String to manipulate"
```

it should be like this

```
 java ShortenerUtilty filepath "String tomanipulate"
```

If file path contains space need to enclosed within double quote (")